# What is the correct way to yield values from events?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, generator

Suppose a function that gets called on messages like this:

```py
def on_message(message):
    yield message # can't use return value
```

I wish to create a function that uses a generator continuously yield the messages:

```py
def get_all_messages():
  # yield from on_message()
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

I have thought of these possible ways:

1. Using files or `os.pipe`. Create a file and write to it on the `on_message` function, and in the `get_all_messages` function read from that file in an infinite loop and yield the buffer. This is less preferable as I would have to create temporary files, and also convert all of my data to strings or raw bytes.
2. Using sockets for IO in a similar way to how I would use files. This is also less preferable then I have to create a server and connect to it.

Comment: I don't understand why you ask for files and pipes, when the code you show has nothing to do with it. Please clarify. Also, do you know the syntax `async for` ?

Comment: Consider using a queue.Queue().  `on_message` writes a message to a queue and `get_all_messages` removes them, one at a time in a `while True:` loop.  The methods are in different threads.